# tensorflow 1.0 RNN loss stagnates

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to write a simple RNN in tensorflow 1.0 (I cannot swuitch to tf 2.0 for compatibility reasons) and am seeing some strange behaviour. For the first 4 iterations the loss changes and then stagnates at a constant value. Changing the learning rate or any other parameter does not change this behaviour and the result is quite bad. I am assuming that there is an error in my code but since I am very unfamiliar with tf1.0, I cannot seem to find it. Does anyone see the problem?

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
import matplotlib.cm as cm

import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(5)  # 5

import sys
sys.path.append("..")

# ===================================================================================
#                                   Hyperparameters
# ===================================================================================

batch_size = 300

# number of optimization steps
reps = 100 

lr = 0.01 
b1 = 0.9
b2 = 0.999
eps = 1e-08 

# ===================================================================================
#                                   Training data
# ===================================================================================
# load the training data from the provided files

train_data = np.load('./inputs_train.npy') 
test_data = np.load('./inputs_test.npy')
train_y = np.load('./labels_train.npy').reshape(batch_size, 1) 
test_y = np.load('./labels_test.npy').reshape(batch_size, 1) 

########################### Classical NN ################################

d = 4 # number of predictors
p = 16 # best: 16
input_neurons = d
output_neurons = 1

# initialise hidden state

h = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, p])
hid = np.ones((batch_size, p))

input_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, input_neurons])

input_matrix = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[input_neurons, p]))
offset_input = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[p]))

hidden_matrix = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[p, p]))
offset_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[p]))

output_matrix = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[p, output_neurons]))
offset_output = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[output_neurons]))

h_t = tf.nn.elu(tf.matmul(input_layer, input_matrix)+offset_input + tf.matmul(h, hidden_matrix)+offset_hidden)
output_layer = tf.nn.elu(tf.matmul(h_t, output_matrix) + offset_output)

parameters = [input_matrix, offset_input, hidden_matrix, offset_hidden, output_matrix, offset_output]

# ===================================================================================
#                      Define the loss function
# ===================================================================================

hidden = h_t
pred = output_layer

output_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(pred-output_data)**2) 

# ===================================================================================
#                      Perform the optimization
# ===================================================================================

# we choose the Adam optimizer
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr,
                                    beta1=b1,
                                    beta2=b2,
                                    epsilon=eps)
min_op = optimiser.minimize(loss)

session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print('Beginning optimization')

loss_vals = []

for i in range(reps+1):

    loss_, predictions, hid, _ = session.run(
        [loss, pred, hidden, min_op],
        feed_dict={input_layer: train_data, h: hid, output_data: train_y})
    loss_vals.append(loss_)
        
    print('Step: {} Loss: {}'.format(i, loss_))


Beginning optimization
Step: 0 Loss: 1.1433227062225342
Step: 1 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 2 Loss: 1.245898723602295
Step: 3 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 4 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 5 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 6 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 7 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 8 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 9 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 10 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 11 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 12 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 13 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 14 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 15 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 16 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 17 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 18 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 19 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
Step: 20 Loss: 1.2459838390350342
...
```

Comment: This is  not a RNN, your input does not even have timesteps on it.

Comment: I tried to simply output the hidden state at each step and feed it into the next step, but I wasn't sure how to do that in tf1.0. I'm guessing that the way I tried doesn't actually do what I wanted it to do. Do you have a recommendation on how change the code to implement that?

Comment: Use Keras, don't try to implement advanced algorithms manually.